# If $R$ is a local ring, the morphism of schemes $f: \operatorname{Spec} R \to X$ is determined by the image of the closed point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes, local-rings

I’m taking an introductory course on Scheme theory. In one of the proofs of the course, we were considering all morphisms of schemes $f: \operatorname{Spec} R \to X$, where $X$ is a scheme and $R$ is a local ring of maximal ideal $\frak{m}$. (Let's call $\{y_0\}=V(\mathfrak{m})$ the closed point associated to that maximal ideal.)

In the proof, this is written as follows:

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{Sch}(\operatorname{Spec}R,X)=\{ (x,\phi), \text{ where } x\in X \text{ and } \phi:\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow R \text{ is a local morphism} \}$$

I'm trying to understand why. Here are my thoughts in case it's helpful to see where my confusion stems from (you might ignore them if they're incorrect):

I know that in general, a morphism of schemes $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a morphism of ringed spaces $(f,f^\flat)$ such that for all $y \in Y$ the induced homomorphism on stalks $f^{\sharp}_y: \mathcal{O}_{X,f(y)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ is a local ring homomorphism. In our case, I can see that the morphism $\phi$ given in the proof corresponds to $f^\sharp_y:\mathcal{O}_{X,f(y)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R,y}$ for some continuous map $f:\operatorname{Spec}R\rightarrow X$ and some $y\in \operatorname{Spec}R$. Since they wrote $R$ as the codomain of $\phi$, I deduce that they're considering that $y=y_0$ is the closed point in $R$, because then $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}R,y}=R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R$ (since $R$ is local).

So what I understand they mean is that

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{Sch}(\operatorname{Spec}R,X)=\{ (f(y_0),f_{f(y_0)}^{\flat}), \text{ where }f_{f(y_0)}^{\flat} : \mathcal{O}_{X,f(y_0)}\rightarrow R\}$$

...but this seems to imply that any morphism of schemes $f: \operatorname{Spec} R \to X$ is determined uniquely by the image of the closed point by the underlying map (and it's induced homomorphism on the stalk at the image of that point). If that's correct, I don't see the reason.

Comment: The answer is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021813/every-morphism-from-spec-r-to-x-factors-through-spec-mathcalo-x-x-whe?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @MPos Sorry, I couldn’t reply earlier. Thank you. There’s a step I don’t understand in that answer though, why does fact $(2)$ imply that $\text{Spec} R \rightarrow X$ factors as $\text{Spec} R \rightarrow U \subset X$?

Comment: The point of that is to let you factor $\operatorname{Spec} R\to X$ as $\operatorname{Spec} R \to U \to X$ for $U$ an affine open neighborhood of $x$. This is exactly accomplished by [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4820248/if-f-operatornamespec-r-to-x-is-a-map-with-r-local-and-with-closed-point); the generalization method is just a slightly different take on it.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you, I think all is clear now.